# Hide webpart based on Sharepoint list value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am looking for JavaScript to hide a webpart based on a field value in a display form.

Scenario: I have added 2 webparts to display form from different lists and I need to hide webpart 2 based on webpart 1's value.

Example: Webpart 1 has status = "Approved" and need to hide the webpart 2 if not equal to "Approved".

Comment: Are both of the webparts custom ones that you created (and can control) or are they OOTB/3rd party?

Comment: Both are custom webparts created and added in a display form of Webpart 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about this, and it really depends on exactly what you are doing. You haven't given us a ton of information to go with.

The JavaScript itself to do what you are looking for is pretty simple. You could do it with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theButton").click(function () {
        var txtInput = $("#txtInput").val();
        if (txtInput == "Approved") {
            $("#two").show();
        } else {
            $("#two").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/tadams88/6Mmb9/

Instead of making it a click function you could just have it run on document.ready.

The other way that I see you could go about this is using connected web parts. You can read up on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765(v=office.14).aspx

Connected web parts lets one web part pass a value to another, which could mean the first web part could tell the second whether or not to display.